# Keep catch block single-line?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

This is my original code:

```
try { Something1(); }
catch { Something2(); }
```

If I format code it becomes like this:

```
try { Something1(); }
catch
{
    Something2();
}
```

*(Currently, I've configured ReSharper before and `try`, `if` etc. blocks keeps single-line)*

I want to keep my single-line `catch` block like `try` block.

What should I configure to handle this?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do this? I can't find any good reason to need this. The less `catch` you have, the cleaner the code is. If you want to use it single line that means you have a lot of them... However this comment is out of scope so good luck.

Comment: format code means with ctrl+K+D?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin I'm not sure about my coding style but I wonder how to do it. I love my curly brackets and single-line flow-control statements :)

Comment: How are you formatting code. Is it ctrl + K + D

Comment: `catch(Exception ex) { Something2(ex); }`, you find it more readable than having it on 4 lines?

Comment: As far as I know, this is just a bug in resharper. I don't know how or why they missed something this simple but they did.

@SébastienSevrin YES! It is *much* more readable in a single line than it is vomited onto multiples. It's inconsistent behavior besides. If a single-statement try is formatted into one line, a single-statement catch should be as well. The inconsistency is UGLY.